# Is it posible to create virtual input device on non root Android?

Tags: android, c

Is it posible to create virtual input device on non root Android ? Yes or NO ?

I tried this

```
int fd = open("/dev/uinput", O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
```

but result is -1.
I tried this too:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod +0666 /dev/uinput");
```

but with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that create device on non root phone in C is imposible, but the workaround exists. Solution is AccessibilityService implemented in Java in Android.